# How to find matches and start and endcolumn of matches at same time?

Tags: regex, vim, pattern-matching, match

To find matches line by line I do this:

```
for i in range(0,line("$"))
  exe i.'s/mysearch/\=add(matches,submatch(0))[-1]/g'
endfor
```

Then I do something like this to find the start and endcolumn:

```
let startcol  = match(getline(i), '\C'.matches[i])
let endcol = matchend(getline(i), '\C'.matches[i])
```

But I noted that this gives not always the right value p.e. if there are `\zs` and `\ze` delimiters in a search or if there are more of the same matches on a single line.

Is there a way to find the start/endcol of the matches within the search
`exe i.'s/mysearch/\=add(matches,submatch(0))[-1]/g'`?